# extern struct declaration in C

Tags: c

I'm fairly new to C, hence could someone please help me understand the below struct declaration?

```
extern struct server_module* module_open (const char* module_path);
```

Per my understanding, `module_open` is pointer to the `struct server_module`, however, didn't understand the last part of the statement i.e. `(const char* module_path)`

Comment: Discover https://www.cdecl.org

Comment: @IgorS.K.: cdecl.org reports a syntax error for the declaration in the question. It apparently fails with named parameters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, looks like it does fail. But it is still a worthy tool to know about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extern struct server_module* module_open (const char* module_path);` declares `module_open` to be a function taking a parameter named `module_path` of type `const char *` and returning a `struct server-module *`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`module_open` is a function which returns pointer to `struct server_module`

and   `const char* module_path` is input argument type. Means function takes character string as an input
`extern` keyword is used to tell compiler that symbol is exist in different file